# How can I go about passing data from a HTML form to a JavaScript file that handles AJAX calls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

How can I go about passing data from a HTML form to a JavaScript file that handles AJAX calls?

**submission_form.php**

```
<?php echo elgg_view("input/file", array("name" => "icon", "class" => "icon")); ?>

<p>
    <?= elgg_view('input/text', ["name" => 'title', "class" => "title"]); ?>
</p>
```

**submit.js**

```
function myajax_function(){
    var Ajax = require('elgg/Ajax');
    var ajax = new Ajax();

    ajax.action('service_comments/add_service_comment', {
        data: {
            picture: 1,
            description: 2
        },
    }).done(function (output, statusText, jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.AjaxData.status == -1) {
            return;
        }
        alert(output.sum);
        alert(output.product);
    });
}
```

**action file :** *submission_form.php*

```
// Not working
$title = get_input('title');

// I'm not sure how to go about extracting the file from input/file and text from input/text
```

Thank you all in advance.

> > I'm working with [Elgg](https://elgg.org/) version 2.X, and following [this tutorial: Ajax Actions](http://learn.elgg.org/en/2.0/guides/ajax.html#actions)but I think this would be standadised (data exchange from HTML to Javascript to PHP for AJAX persistence)

Comment: I think, the only tag you should put is elgg. the other tags like JS,php,jquery html, ajax are misleading. so please remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add a class or ID to the form tag.

```
echo elgg_view_form('submission_form', array('class' => 'elgg-form-submission_form'), array());
```

then in your JS file

```
$(".elgg-form-submission_form").submit(function( event ) {
    $.post("service_comments/add_service_comment", $(this).serialize(), function(result) {

}
```